# Must each Knex command in a transaction be submitted only after the previous command's promise has been fulfilled if their order is important?

Tags: transactions, knex.js

I'm using the second form of knex transactions (e.g., with 'transacting'). However, this question is probably valid for the first form as well.

The documentation sample shows this:

```
// Using trx as a transaction object:
knex.transaction(function(trx) {

  const books = [
    {title: 'Canterbury Tales'},
    {title: 'Moby Dick'},
    {title: 'Hamlet'}
  ];

  knex.insert({name: 'Old Books'}, 'id')
    .into('catalogues')
    .transacting(trx)
    .then(function(ids) {
      books.forEach((book) => book.catalogue_id = ids[0]);
      return knex('books').insert(books).transacting(trx);
    })
    .then(trx.commit)
    .catch(trx.rollback);
})
```

Two "insert" commands are being executed in the transaction. The second one is submitted only after the first one's promise has been fulfilled (i.e., in the promise's 'then' callback).

In the above example this is necessary, since the second command can only be formulated after the result of the first command has come back.

However, there are cases where multiple commands can be formulated in advance. As such, one might execute code like this:

```
promise1 = knex('table1').insert(...).transacting(trx).then(...)
promise2 = knex('table2').insert(...).transacting(trx).then(...)

Use Promise.all to wait for completion and eventually commit or rollback.
```

In fact, this code will execute. Knex will queue the commands and send them out over the connection assigned to the transaction one at a time.

However, **and this is the gist of my question**, empirical evidence while using knex with PostgreSQL seems to show that the order in which the commands are sent to the database is not maintained. In other words, the order in which the commands were submitted to knex is not necessarily the order in which they are sent to the database. It seems that the only way to guarantee that commands are sent in a specific order is to create a promise chain whereby each command is submitted only after the previous command has been fulfilled.

Can anyone comment on this? Is this by design? Might this be a bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> However, and this is the gist of my question, empirical evidence while using knex with PostgreSQL seems to show that the order in which the commands are sent to the database is not maintained. In other words, the order in which the commands were submitted to knex is not necessarily the order in which they are sent to the database. It seems that the only way to guarantee that commands are sent in a specific order is to create a promise chain whereby each command is submitted only after the previous command has been fulfilled.

Sounds like your code doesn't do what you think it does.

Knex sends queries to the database driver in that order, how you tell it to execute them (by `await`ing query builder or by executing `.then()` method).

If you execute more than 1 query to the same transaction, before earlier has finished `node-pg` driver buffers the second query and sends it only after the first query has first returned its response.

> Use Promise.all to wait for completion and eventually commit or rollback.

If there is no error thrown, this should work.

`Promise.all([p1,p2fails,p3,p4,p5])`

However if there is exception thrown for example from `p2fails` promise, then `Promise.all` will reject instantly and `rollback` will be executed. After that `p3`,`p4` and `p5` are still tried to be executed, since they were already buffered in `node-pg` to be sent.

Would be safer, more memory efficient (query is stored twice, once in knex builder and once as buffered raw query inside pg driver with large inserts this might be significant) and easier to just wait each query to return before sending the next one. Using Promise.all here doesn't even give any additional concurrency benefits, since queries are still executed sequentially through the same connection.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! For the sake of my question, let's ignore the Promise.all stuff and issues of memory efficiency. I am aware of the queue maintained internally by the pg driver and as such was surprised when we saw the commands hitting the database server out of order. While investigating this, I discovered that in addition to the queue maintained by the driver, it seems that knex is maintaining an additional queue via the tarn library. Is this true? Is it possible that this extra layer of queuing might be causing what we are seeing?

Comment: No that is not true. Tarn is handling pool of connections. When knex starts transaction knex asks a connection from pool for that transaction. After that tarn is not involved except when transaction is committed / rolled back the connection gets returned to the tarn connection pool. In knex there is no extra layers buffering executed queries. They are sent directly to db driver (which is `pg` in this case) when query is executed.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I understand that tarn handles the pool of connections. I was under the impression that if no connections are available when a new transaction begins then queries of that transaction will be queued somewhere until a connection becomes available. If this is not true, can you provide some details on how such a case is handled? I really appreciate your help on this. Thank you!

Comment: If there is no connections available and more connections cannot be created, then tarn waits until some other connection is returned to the pool or until acquire timeout. So inside tarn is maintained list of pending acquire connection requests, but it doesn't buffer any db queries. If connection cannot be acquired from pool, then no queries are made. In case of transaction the connection has been already acquired and reserved when transaction was started.

Comment: Thanks for this ongoing dialog. Let's assume tarn waits and a connection is indeed returned to the pool. At this stage, tarn will acquire it and presumably hand it back to knex for usage. Meanwhile, if promise chaining wasn't used, knex will have accumulated multiple queries for this transaction. So now that knex has received a connection, will it issue the commands in their original order? Would that not require that knex also maintain some kind of queue for such cases? If no such queue exists, could that possibly explain why the database sometimes receives commands out of order?

Comment: No SQL queries are sent to connection if acquiring it from pool fails. When you are inside knex.transaction(trx => {}) handler, the connection is already acquired from pool. So in your case that scenario is not possible, that you would send SQL queries to transcation before connection is already acquired.

Comment: `If no such queue exists, could that possibly explain why the database sometimes receives commands out of order?` - answer to that was already in the main answer "Sounds like your code doesn't do what you think it does." I don't mean to sound arrogant, but without complete code that can reproduce the problem, there is no way for me to spot if it indeed is user issue or not (most of the time with these kind of reports it is). If you have complete reproduction code and I cannot see any problems with that, then I would need to start wondering if there indeed is a bug in knex in those parts.

Comment: Thank you. Your comments are very helpful. Specifically the fact that the callback passed to knex.transaction is only called after the connection has been acquired. I will try to dig deeper and comment again if I am able to get more details. Thank you very much for your time on this.

Comment: Final update on this: We found the real cause of what we experienced and it is not related to knex. Thanks again for all your help.